# Using character literals as terminals in bison

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to understand flex/bison, but the documentation is a bit difficult for me, and I've probably grossly misunderstood something.  Here's a test case: http://namakajiri.net/misc/bison_charlit_test/

File "a" contains the single character 'a'.  "foo.y" has a trivial grammar like this:

```
%%

file: 'a' ;
```

The generated parser can't parse file "a"; it gives a syntax error.

The grammar "bar.y" is almost the same, only I changed the character literal for a named token:

```
%token TOK_A;

%%

file: TOK_A;
```

and then in bar.lex:

```
a       { return TOK_A; }
```

This one works just fine.

What am I doing wrong in trying to use character literals directly as bison terminals, like in the docs?

I'd like my grammar to look like "statement: selector '{' property ':' value ';' '}'" and not "statement: selector LBRACE property COLON value SEMIC RBRACE"...

I'm running bison 2.5 and flex 2.5.35 in debian wheezy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Rewrite*

The problem is a runtime problem, not a compile time problem.

The trouble is that you have two radically different lexical analyzers.

The `bar.lex` analyzer recognizes an `a` in the input and returns it as a TOK_A and ignores everything else.

The `foo.lex` analyzer echoes every single character, but that's all.

#### foo.lex — as written

```
%{
#include "foo.tab.h"
%}

%%
```

#### foo.lex — equivalent

```
%{
#include "foo.tab.h"
%}

%%
. { ECHO; }
```

#### foo.lex — required

```
%{
#include "foo.tab.h"
%}

%%
. { return *yytext; }
```

---

### Working code

Here's some working code with diagnostic printing in place.

#### foo-lex.l

```
%%
. { printf("Flex: %d\n", *yytext); return *yytext; }
```

#### foo.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(char *s);
%}

%%

file: 'a' { printf("Bison: got file!\n") }
    ;

%%

int main(void)
{
    yyparse();
}

void yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

#### Compilation and execution

```
$ flex foo-lex.l
$ bison foo.y
$ gcc -o foo foo.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
$ echo a | ./foo
Flex: 97
Bison: got file!

$
```

---

Point of detail: how did that blank line get into the output?  Answer: the lexical analyzer put it there.  The pattern `.` does not match a newline, so the newline was treated as if there was a rule:

```
\n    { ECHO; }
```

This is why the input was accepted.  If you change the `foo-lex.l` file to:

```
%%
.       { printf("Flex-1: %d\n", *yytext); return *yytext; }
\n      { printf("Flex-2: %d\n", *yytext); return *yytext; }
```

and then recompile and run again, the output is:

```
$ echo a | ./foo
Flex-1: 97
Bison: got file!
Flex-2: 10
syntax error
$
```

with no blank lines.  This is because the grammar doesn't allow a newline to appear in a valid 'file'.

Comment: If you really want no lexer at all, don't bother with a .l file at all -- just stick `int yylex() { return getchar(); }` in the third section of your .y file.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: almost — you have to map EOF to 0: `int yylex(void) { int c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) return 0; else return c; }`.  This also reports ASCII NUL `'\0'` as EOF too.

Comment: You don't have to map 0 to EOF, Bison's parsers recognize 0 as EOF.

Comment: @akim: True; all Yacc-based parsers treat a token value 0 as 'end of token stream'.  The trouble is that when you use `return getchar();`, the value returned on EOF is negative (usually -1), and that is not recognized as 'end of token stream' by Yacc-based parsers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right. Actually, I personally discourage from using char directly as return value for `yylex`.  Using an enum type is much safer.  Yes, I do mean that you shouldn't `return '+';`, but rather `return PLUS;` which is more code in the scanner.  But it's also much safer as you don't risk to jam your parser by feeding it with token types that don't exist.